# Long table centres the table

Tags: tables, ltablex

I have a table like this

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
    Cap & The underlying is a an interest rate cap\\
    Floor & The underlying is an interest rate floor\\
    Swap & The underlying is a vanilla swap\\
\end{tabularx}
```

and several others that have many more rows. So I can allow the tables to spill over pages, I have `\usepackage{ltablex}` in my preamble.

But doing this causes the tables to be centred on the page which is not typographically pleasing.

How can I have (i) long tables with (ii) the same formatting as their shorter cousins?

Comment: Please always post an example document that shows the problem. If you are using `ltablex` then you are presumably again specifying the table is `\linewidth` wide and `X` column, so centering (or any other alignment) has no effect, the table is full width. (tables set with `lX` are almost always better set as a list)

Answer (score 5):

The ltablex package messes about with the table column specifications.

You can switch this off by using the command `\keepXColumns`. Put this after `\usepackage{ltablex}` in the preamble.