# itemize within tabularx does not work when ltablex is loaded

Tags: tables, enumerate, itemize, tabularx, ltablex

I need this code to be compilable without errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathdots, paralist}
\usepackage{ltablex} % uncommenting this line will work

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
% & influential variables &
\textbf{Setting 1:} & This is my  description $X_{\text{bla}} \in \{1, \hdots , 20\}$.\\
\textbf{Setting 2:} & This splits into
\begin{compactitem}
        \item First item
        \item Second item
\end{compactitem} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I am getting the error `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{tabularx}`. If I remove the line `\usepackage{ltablex}` it will work.
However, I need the ltablex package and therefore I am looking for a possibility to let the code above be compilable. Any suggestions?

Comment: see if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214299/long-table-centres-the-table/214305#214305 helps

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ltablex` changes too much really, if you must merge `longtable` and `tabularx` I'd probably use `ltxtable`, but 99% of the time that i see tables set with `{lX}` they would be better set as a list, which naturally expands to full width and naturally breaks over a page, without any of the contortions that `tabularx` and `longtable` do.

However `ltablex` has a `\keepXColumns` to make it be a bit more compatible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathdots, paralist}
\usepackage{ltablex} % uncommenting this line will work

\keepXColumns
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
% & influential variables &
\textbf{Setting 1:} & This is my  description $X_{\text{bla}} \in \{1, \hdots , 20\}$.\\
\textbf{Setting 2:} & This splits into
\begin{compactitem}
        \item First item
        \item Second item
\end{compactitem} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround  consists in inserting your `compactitem` environment in a \parbox of a suitable size. However there is a small problem with the vertical spacing of the environment (see image). It can be solved with the `enumitem` version of the compact itemize. Moreover, `enumitem` lists are easily customisable.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathdots, paralist}
\usepackage{ltablex} % uncommenting this line will work
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
% & influential variables &
\textbf{Setting 1:} & This is my description $X_{\text{bla}} \in \{1, \hdots , 20\}$.\\
\textbf{Setting 2:} & This splits into\par
\parbox{10cm}{%
\begin{compactitem}
 \item First item
 \item Second item
\end{compactitem}
}%
\\
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
% & influential variables &
\textbf{Setting 1:} & This is my description $X_{\text{bla}} \in \{1, \hdots , 20\}$.\\
\textbf{Setting 2:} & This splits into\par
\parbox{10cm}{%
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, topsep=1pt, wide = 1em]
 \item First item
 \item Second item
\end{itemize}
}%
\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but using a parbox forces you to specify a width which negates the point of an X column, you may as well not use tabularx and just use `p` which will have  the same result but vastly more efficient.